# Deleting duplicates from composite Primary key in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL server 2012.
I have two tables with identical structure. (Say there are four columns - ID, C2, C3, C4)
I want to copy data from Table1 to Table2.

The only difference between the two tables is that Table1 contains the local ID in the 'ID' field and table 2 should have the global ID.

There is another third table that contains this mapping between the localID and the global ID.
(multiple local ID's can be mapped to one Global ID)

*Example:
ID 'abcd' in russia can be global ID 123
ID 'cdef' in china can be global ID 123
therefore abcd in russia is basically cdef in china (this mapping is stored in table3)*

I want to take the GlobalID from table3 corresponding to the local ID that we have in Table1 and insert them into table2.

Table2 has a primary key constraint defined on the column ID+C2.

The problem is that there are high chance we'll have duplicate data - So we want to insert only distinct combination of ID+C2. (clustered PK)

Can someone please help me with this? Sorry if this is confusing.

I right now have this query, but it doesnt eliminates duplicates when copying data from T1 to T2 and thus I get an error on PK.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
(ID,
C2,
C3,
C4)

SELECT  T3.ID,
        T1.C2,
        T1.C3,
        T1.C4   

FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
```

Comment: Move or copy? (I.e. keep data in original location?)

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2835541). I suggest posting example code or at very least your DDL.

Comment: @ChrisPickford - Hello Chris, I'm asking for help in creating the scripts so not sure how I can provide you example code here.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPickford, does it looks any better now?

Comment: What happens if there is two local ids for one global id that have different values? If you are sure that will never happen, you can use `DISTINCT` in the select. Otherwise, you will have to figure out what to do with fitting two values in one row, i.e. something must be discarded

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess you want something like

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (globalID)
    SELECT DISTINCT m.globalID from Mapping m inner join Table1 t 
          on t.country = m.country and t.localId = m.localID
```

You can use any select, so alter it for your needs.